# Unaliasing a global alias in zsh

Tags: unix, alias, zsh

I had defined a global alias in my zsh shell using "alias -g" . When I am trying to unalias it, the shell throws the following error :  "unalias: no such hash table element".

Any pointers on how to unalias a globally defined alias?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to escape it while attempting to `unalias`.  Try saying:

```
unalias \aliasname
```

instead of

```
unalias aliasname
```

---

Since it's a global alias, the shell would substitute it anywhere on the command line unless you escape it.