# How do you remove or delete a global alias from Zshell?

Tags: alias, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm using ZShell terminal and cannot find anywhere online how to remove a global alias I just created with:

```
alias -g API_KEY="XXXXXXXXX"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is:

```
unalias \API_KEY
```

Didn't know the nomenclature was 'unalias'. Can also be found via this post [unaliasing-a-global-alias-in-zsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343973/unaliasing-a-global-alias-in-zsh)

Comment: If you question is a duplicate of another, close it, don't answer.